# Electron emission and photoelectric effect affected by intensity

Tags: wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect, photon-emission, intensity

It is said that when visible light is directed onto a metal surface, it doesn't emit electrons from the surface because intensity doesn't affect it. However, then it is said (relating to the equation) that the rate of emission doesn't depend on frequency but does depend on intensity. How is that possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The three laws of the photoelectric effect are as follows:

1. Electron emission from a surface exposed to radiation stops when the frequency of incident radiation is less than a particular value of frequency called the threshold frequency.
2. The number of electrons emitted per unit time is directly proportional to the intensity of incident radiation.
3. Kinetic energy of the emitted electrons is directly proportional to the frequency of incident radiation.

The energy of a photon is given by

\begin{equation}
E = h \nu
\end{equation}

Where $h$ is the Plank's constant and $\nu$ is the frequency of the radiation. The energy of the photon has no relation with the intensity of incident radiation. So a photon of insufficient frequency (i.e. lower than threshold frequency) cannot cause photoelectric emission. However, when the frequency of incident radiation is more than the threshold frequency, the number of electrons emitted per unit time is proportional to the intensity, which is, in turn, proportional to the number of photons incident per unit time.

Comment: Points #3 and #1 contradict each other...

Comment: @DJohnThanks for pointing out. It was a typo.